What is the difference between power and authority in Luke 4:36?
What is the difference between power and authority in Luke 4:36 ?

Welcome to the Biblical Hermeneutics forum, James. Here's a couple of questions to think about in light of your question. How would you describe a person with power but no authority? Where does authority come from?

ἐν ἐξουσίᾳ [authority] καὶ δυνάμει [power] (NA28)
Authority meant the demons were obligated to obey Jesus' command [the ability to delegate the choice], and power meant Jesus had the power to physically force the demons to obey [the ability to do].

ἐξουσία, ας, ἡ ... ① a state of control over someth., freedom of choice, right ... ② potential or resource to command, control, or govern, capability, might, power ... ③ the right to control or command, authority, absolute power, warrant ... ④ power exercised by rulers or others in high position by virtue of their office, ruling power, official power ... ⑤ bearer of ruling authority ... ⑥ the sphere in which power is exercised, domain ... ③ a deed that exhibits ability to function powerfully, deed of power, miracle, wonder ... --
Arndt, W., Danker, F. W., Bauer, W., & Gingrich, F. W. (2000). In A Greek-English lexicon of the New Testament and other early Christian literature (3rd ed., p. 352-353). University of Chicago Press.


δύναμις, εως, ἡ ... ① potential for functioning in some way, power, might, strength, force, capability ... ② ability to carry out someth., ability, capability ... ④ someth. that serves as an adjunct of power, resource ... ⑤ an entity or being, whether human or transcendent, that functions in a remarkable manner, power ... ⑥ the capacity to convey thought, meaning ...
--
Arndt, W., Danker, F. W., Bauer, W., & Gingrich, F. W. (2000). In A Greek-English lexicon of the New Testament and other early Christian literature (3rd ed., p. 263). University of Chicago Press.

Note the meaning of the verbal form of this noun (generated with Logos Bible Software).


Luke 4:36 says (BLB) -

And astonishment came upon all, and they were speaking to one another,
saying, "What word is this, that He commands the unclean spirits with
authority and power, and they come out?"

The two Greek words involved here are with their BDAG meanings:
ἐξουσία (exousia) = "Authority"

a state of control over something, freedom of choice, right, eg, 2 Thess 3:9, John 10:18, 1 Cor 9:44, Heb 13:10, Rev 13:5, etc
potential or resource to command, control, or govern, capability, might, power, eg, Rev 9:10, 19, 11:6, 13:2, 4, 12, 18:1, 20:6, Luke 4:32, Matt 9:8, Acts 8:19, Mark 3:15, Luke 12:4, John 1:12, etc
the right to control or command, authority, absolute power, warrant, eg, Acts 26:12, Matt 21;33, 24, 27, Mark 11:28, 29, 33, Luke 20:2, 8, etc
power exercised by rulers or others in high position by virtue of their office, ruling power, official power, eg, Luke 19:17, 20:20, John 19:10, etc.

Three more meanings are also provided by BDAG, not relevant here.
δύναμις (dunamis) = "power"

potential for functioning in some way, power, might, strength, force, capability


(a) general: Acts 1:8, Rev 17:13, Matt 22:29, Mark 12:24, Luke 22:69, Rom 1:16, etc
(b) specifically, the power that works wonders, eg, Matt 14;2, Mark 5:30, 6:14, Luke 4:36, 5:17, 6:19, 8:46, Acts 10:38, Gal 3:5, 1 Cor 12:28, etc


ability to carry out something, ability, capability, Heb 11;11, etc
a deed that exhibits ability to function powerfully, deed of power, miracle, wonder

BDAG lists three more sub-meanings.
Thus, it is immediately apparent that the meanings of these two words overlap.  However, in Luke 4:36, the speaker appears to be stating that Jesus has unbridled ability to perform great signs and wonders, miracles that have never been seen before.  That "authority and power" appear to form a double emphasis that Jesus has such.
